# Parse Nth matching column and split via single regular expression

Tags: regex

Given below input line, I need to get 4th column values on either side of slash character via single regex.

```
2323         va1/val1.2         val2/val2.2         val3/val3.2            DOWN
```

Regex should match `"val3/"`. Likewise another regexp could match `"/val3.2"`
Spacing between columns is fixed and 2nd,3rd,4th column pattern is `"AnyString/AnyOtherString".`**/**` would always be there.

I am using a custom tool which expects input as regexp so my choices are limited. I am able parse this via Javascript code but looking for a single regex to have match and split of Nth column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get 4th column with following regex :

```
(?:[^ ]* +){3}([^ /]*)
```

Note that you need to return the group(1).

See demo https://regex101.com/r/kM3rN2/2

Comment: That is where I am stuck. I need to split in one regex only. So regex should match "val3/".

Comment: @Sachin Yep, you just need to add one `/` in negated character class, check the edit!

Comment: Technically the OP wanted the slash:  (?:[^ ]* +){3}([^ /]*/)

Comment: @Gary_W yes, you are right. But either one is fine.